# How to take subscription with paypal-checkout?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

We have an existing website that uses the javascript [paypal-checkout](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout), and now we wants to takes subscription payment too.

However, from the [PayPal-checkout docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/), it does not seem to mentioned anything about subscription, or recurring payment.

We noticed that there is this [html based subscription button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_step_1/), but we are unsure how we will be able to use it in our react app.

Wondering if I am missing anything here, or if there exist a better way to take recurring payment.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is no way to do this with PayPal Checkout, should use Subscriptions (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/)

Comment: @Drey, I am using the same API which you have mentioned, but it also not supporting the one time payment for some order of product, although it have one field, named "setup_fee", but its label is not changeable, so at Paypal site it is showing as "One time set up fee", please help me if Subscription API support this,

Comment: Sorry, @harishsharma, didn't use subscription API and have no ability to check now for you